# Half Uncle possibility -fathers side

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, half-aunt-uncle

I recently conducted a DNA test on ancestry.com and I received a strong match with a guy I don’t know . 758cms across 23 segments longest segment 86cm. He is 57 years of age and my father is 70 and i am 44yrs. My sister also on Ancestry and comes up as full sibling to me and high match with the guy -590cms .  Also my 1st cousin is on there(fathers sisters daughter ) shows a lower marking 495cm ,22 segments (longest segment -77cm)

My 1st cousin doesn’t show up as a shared match to the guy but my sister and I do - quite high.  Is this potentially my half uncle ? Dads half brother ?

Answer (score 1):

[DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/758) is the tool for you.

For 758cM, it lists several possible relationships."Half Aunt/Uncle" is one of them, so yes - that could be the relationship.

But it lists several other possible ones - some of which I'm sure you can eliminate given what you know about your family.

Comment: I’ve ruled all them out bar the half uncle.  Now it’s the hard part , getting my father to do the test.  Potentially half sibling.  Which should read 1500cms !?

Comment: Again, DNAPainter. :-) They've got a big database of data behind them, and they say half-siblings should share between 1160-2436 cM.

Comment: "DNAPainter" to me means the DNAPainter tool on that website. I realize the link points to the Shared cM Tool, but...